# Hardware options for canvas printer calibration

Tags: printing, color-management, display-calibration, soft-proofing, icc-profile

I am looking for hardware for calibration of canvas prints.

There are many solutions for monitors (as Datacolor Spyder, X-Rite i1 Display Pro, X-Rite ColorMunki) and paper printers (as Datacolor SpyderPRINT), but what hardware is needed to take color profiles for canvas printers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted online both X-Rite and Datacolor and asked the same question.

Datacolor never responded (it has been few months from then)!

X-Rite contacted me by phone via their local dealer. He asked me my case and gave me a detailed answer with interesting details about getting accurate colors on canvas. I really enjoyed such information from person with much experience! He recommended me **XRite i1Publish Pro 2** as their product for such tasks.

Summary: It seems X-Rite has great support instead of Datacolor!

Answer (score 2):

It is the same process as any printer.

You simply need to print the sample and take measures with the hardware.

http://www.xrite.com/service-support/creating_printing_profiles_with_colormunki_photo_or_colormunki_design

Comment: The document repeats "paper" as printing media. Canvas is not mentioned anywhere. So calibrating canvas prints is kind of using the tool out of its specifications.

Comment: It does not matter what the base is. It is one methodology for print, regardless is fabric or paper or plastic.

Comment: Possibly it is correct, but official documents assert that only paper media is supported.

Comment: You were generally right! I opened an requests to X-Rite and Datacolor. I am upvoting your answer but I will post my entire experience as a new answer.

Comment: Nice. That kind of feedback is good.